# Making website responsive in Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

I'm currently developing a website using Joomla. I have problem to make my website responsive. My current solution is adding CSS codes into the HTML, but it does not work. Can someone give me a solution on how make my website responsive without using extension or changing the template. Thank You.

Comment: I didn't work with Joomla but there should be a `style.css` file or `responsive.css` somewhere in theme documents (like WordPress). You should work with them. For example add this media query `@media only screen and (min-width: 580px) and (max-width: 760px) {your CSS here}` to add dedicated style for screen devices between 580px and 760px. If you google for `media query`, there are lots of resources.

Answer (score 0):

If the template you're using isn't already responsive you're really making things hard for yourself by wanting to stick with it.

The way css is loaded varies according to template, so you need to check yours to see what mechanism(s) it gives you for including your own css.  Again, if there isn't one, you're probably best to get a new one, it will make life so much easier.

If they've implemented a mechanism for you to use, that will probably define the file you can use.
There *may* be an option in the template admin panel to enter css.
Without knowing which template you're using and how it does that, it's pretty hard to give a very useful answer.